# JWT Authentication - Having trouble requesting the Token for a newly registered User

Tags: php, json, api, cakephp, jwt

I am trying to add JWT authentication to my cakephp3 Rest API, following this [tutorial](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/)

I'm having trouble verifying a Token Request after I have created the /register action in my `UsersController.php` file and having registered a new user. (I have changed the words 'Users' with 'Artists' because of the type of App I am making). So, having registered the new Artist (User) I am shown a 201 Status Code saying it was successful hence giving me my "token" for that Artist (User). I then had this verified by browsing to http://jwt.io/ and pasting the token in to it, which also displayed back to me as a success. Moving forwards, I am now trying to implement JWT Token Requests in my `ArtistsController.php` file by requesting the Tokens by JSON posting the Artist's (User's) email and password. Here is my code for the `ArtistsController.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;
use App\Controller\Api\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use Cake\Utility\Security;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class ArtistsController extends AppController
{   
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'token']);
    } 

    //Artists registration
    public function add()
    {
        $this->Crud->on('afterSave', function(Event $event) {
            if ($event->subject->created) {
                $this->set('data', [
                    'id' => $event->subject->entity->id,
                    'token' => JWT::encode(
                        [
                            'sub' => $event->subject->entity->id,
                            'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                        ],
                    Security::salt())
                ]);
                $this->Crud->action()->config('serialize.data', 'data');
            }
        });
        return $this->Crud->execute();
    } 

    //Verify Token request
    public function token()
    {
        $artist = $this->Auth->identify();
        if (!$artist) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or password');
        }
        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'sub' => $artist['id'],
                    'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                ],
                Security::salt())
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
    }

    public $paginate = [
        'page' => 1,
        'limit' => 500,
        'maxLimit' => 500,
        'contain' => ['Parlours', 'Tags']
    ];
}
```

When I then try to verify the setup by requesting the Token for the newly created artist (user), posting JSON data to my API, using the API testing tool CocoaRestClient it displays:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid email or password",
    "url": "/api/artists/token",
    "code": 401
}
```

Even though the credentials are valid and correct. I have double and triple checked everything on my database and code, not leaving out any little things like commas in my API testing tool. I even registered a new artist (user) just to be sure. Everything was a success before now trying to request the Token (even when the Token has been created and verified).

**Has anyone come across this issue before?**

In theory it should work because the email and password are valid, but it just simply doesn't.

Comment: @RogarSSD, Please help me to answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995364/how-can-we-save-registration-data-in-two-tables-with-jwt-authentication-in-cakep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed auth component configuration in AppController.php with respect to Artist Model i.e., 'userModel' => 'Artists'

Comment: It works! Thank you for that. I've been ripping my hair out about this for so long! You're a star!

Comment: @Sebastian Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.